# How to add a new key:value pair to existing sub object of a mongoDB document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to add a new key:value pair to an existing object of mongoDB document, but no steps are helping me

I tried $each, $push $addtoset but i understood those are for arrays then i tried $det but it is updating the existing key:value pair with new key:value pair

Here is my document

```
    {
    test:"abc",
    test2:"cdf",
    test3:{ 1:"one"}
    }
```

if you observer test3 key in the above document i have already 1:"one" now i want to add new key value in the same object

Like

```
    {
    test:"abc",
    test2:"cdf",
    test3:{ 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"}
    }
```

is it possible in mongoDB?

Here is the mongo Query

```
            let val = parseInt(DYNAMICVALUE)
              var changfeemaildot = (req.session.email).replace(/\./g, '#')
              var seld = {
                _id: ObjectId(rx[0]._id)
              };
              var seldu = {

                $set:{
                emails: {
                   [changfeemaildot]: val
                }
              }
            };

              var collection = 
              connection.get().collection('problems');
              collection.update(seld, seldu, function (err, rail) {
              });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). So your code can be something like this

```
db.collection.update({<your_condition>}, {$set: {"test3.2": "two", "test3.3": "three"}});
```

In your case, it will be something like this

```
var seldu = {$set: {["emails." + changfeemaildot]: val}}
```

Comment: $set is removing old value and adding new value

Comment: at every iteration i need to insert new value that is the problem

Comment: Can you show me your $set query? Because according to its documentation it only updates the document.

Comment: var seldu = {
$set:{
 emails: {
  [DYNAMICKEY]: DYNAMICVALUE
 }
}
};

Comment: Ok , so here you are completely overriding the the object, you can do something like this `{ $set:{ ["emails." +  DYNAMICKEY]: DYNAMICVALUE  } };`

Comment: In the answer, I have not  updated the whole object, but I have added individual keys.

Comment: i tried your solution still it is updating old value, and emails are dynamic FYI

Comment: I tried my solution in local mongo shell its not updating the whole object, its just adding the value, check this [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm2w7lc5mv8yydh/Screenshot%202018-12-25%2003.04.26.png?dl=0), are you doing something similar to this?

Comment: I am really worrying now. why that is not working for me?

Comment: Can you paste some snippet of your code and update your question?

Comment: Updated, please help.

Comment: I still not understanding why you added `email.` as prefix when the email is dynamic

Comment: but email is the key of the object in which you want to add the dynamic key:value, right? If yes, that's why I prefixed your new key with emails, such that your new key is part of emails object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $set with findOneAndUpdate. So your code can be something like this

```
  const { Types, connection } = require("mongoose");

  const productList = await connection.collection('products').find({}).toArray()
    productList.forEach(async function(myDoc) {
        await connection.collection('products').
        updateOne({ productId: Types.ObjectId(myDoc.productId) }, {
            $set: {
                productDisplayId: 'anything you want'
            }
        });
    });
```